# pandas merge rows with overlapping column names using default non-NaN value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, concatenation

There is a list of tables and some configurations, specified in csv format.

I want to use default configuration from *configs*, and override it in *tables* if needed

```
configs = """  
schema|new_name
dbo|{table}
qa|test_{table}
"""

tables = """  
table|schema|new_name
employee|hr|{schema}_{table}
advertisers
users
"""

configs = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(configs), sep='|')  
tables = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(tables), sep='|')
```

I want to cross-join/merge/concatenate/combine them to get a dataframe which contains:

```
final = """
table|schema|new_name

employee|hr|{schema}_{table}
advertisers|dbo|{table}
users|dbo|{table}

employee|hr|{schema}_{table}
advertisers|qa|test_{table}
users|qa|test_{table}
"""
```

If schema is not specified, use 'dbo' schema and 'users/advertisers' table name.
If schema is specified, use 'hr' schema and 'hr_employee' table name.

Basically - when horizontal concat of 2 rows with overlapping column names, create one column using whichever value is not NaN.

What pandas command should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
#cross join both DataFrames
df = tables.merge(configs, suffixes=('','_'), how='cross')

#get columns with suffix _
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('_')]
#remove suffix
new = cols.str.strip('_')
#replace missing values from cols by _ colums
df[new] = df[new].fillna(df[cols].rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_')))
#remove columns with _
df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
         table schema          new_name
0     employee     hr  {schema}_{table}
1     employee     hr  {schema}_{table}
2  advertisers    dbo           {table}
3  advertisers     qa      test_{table}
4        users    dbo           {table}
5        users     qa      test_{table}
```

Comment: that assumes the default value would be in the first row. but these are non-tech user-generated csv files. i want an option to combine 2 rows, so that overlapping column names take the non-Nan value.

Comment: @d-_-b - `that assumes the default value would be in the first row` if not first row what is rule? Looking for row with `dbo` in `schema` ?

Comment: no, it should be value-agnostic. basically - when horizontal concat of 2 rows with overlapping column names, create one column using whichever value is not NaN.

Comment: @d-_-b - Can you add more data for explain why my solution failed? Because `concat` or `merge` is not necessary here (but maybe I am wrong)

Comment: i updated the data to reorder it. now iloc[0] wouldn't work. and it needs to get the data from configs table. there might be a case where no table has the default schema or new_name specified

Comment: @d-_-b - it replace any missing value by first row in `configs`, answer working well in edited data

Comment: ohh, i see, you're filling it using configs.. my bad. i thought u were using the first row of tables.

Comment: what if there are multiple rows in configs. i just simplified the data to illustrate the real need I have - which is to combine rows such that overlapping columns take the non-NaN value. i might do a cross join between the two dataframes

Comment: @d-_-b - then is necessary specify logic - what misisng values are repalced by first row? which by second, third row ?

Comment: i updated data in question - don't think of it as replacing missing row values, which can be arbitrary. think of it as replacing column values. a generic scenario that when joining 2 rows, takes columns from one dataframe and injects them into the other.

Comment: @d-_-b - can you test now?